# How to install full ethereum node for execution client only?

Tags: ethereum, go-ethereum

I have tried to install a full Ethereum node (geth) on Ubuntu hundreds of times, but it keeps getting stuck on 'Looking for peers' and doesn't make any progress. Below are the steps I have taken so far:

Synchronized the date and time to match the Ethereum network timezone.
Disabled the firewall settings.
Tried several different ways to write the rpc, ws, and http ports.
And the others ...
Should I also install a consensus client to set up a full Ethereum node, or is it possible to do it just with geth? If anyone has experience with this, please help me.

Nothing happens, getting tired from that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Looking for peers" means that your Ethereum node cannot find other computers in the peer-to-peer network.

- Your network probably blocks Ethereum connections
- Try installing an Ethereum client on a different computer, in a different network